# Is there a way to prove a boolean operator isn't universal?

Tags: proof-writing, boolean-algebra

In boolean algebra, I could prove an operator is universal by implementing a NAND or NOR gate with it. But is there a way to prove a boolean operator isn't universal?

I would like to know a general method that should work for every (or almost every) incomplete operator.

Right now, I want to prove incompleteness of this operator:

$$ T(w,x,y,z) = (\neg w \lor \neg x \lor \neg y) \oplus (xyz)$$
After simplification I could write it like one of the following:

$$(\neg(wx y)) \oplus (xyz) =wxyz \lor \neg w\neg x \lor \neg w\neg y \lor \neg w\neg z \lor \neg x\neg y \lor \neg x\neg z \lor \neg y\neg z$$

$\oplus$ is the eXclusive OR operator, $\lor$ is OR, and I'm using implicit AND for simple reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though the details generally depend considerably on the specific operator or operators. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/263150/12042) is an example of the kind of argument that can be used. For more information you might read about [*functional completeness*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness).

**Added:** If $T(w,x,y,z)=\neg(wxy)\oplus(xyz)$, then $T(x,x,x,x)=x\lor\neg x=\top$. (I use $\bot$ for **false** and $\top$ for **true**.) Suppose that each of the terms $t_1,t_2,t_3$, and $t_4$ is equivalent either to $x$ or to $\top$. Then $t_1t_2t_3$ is equivalent either to $x$ or to $\top$, as is $t_2t_3t_4$, and $T(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)$ is equivalent to one of $\neg x\oplus x=\top$, $\neg x\oplus\top=x$, $\bot\oplus x=x$, and $\bot\oplus\top=\top$. It follows by induction that every term built up from a single variable $x$ using $T$ is equivalent either to $x$ or to $\top$. In particular, $T$ cannot generate $\neg x$ and therefore is not universal.

Comment: Why it's sufficient to show incompleteness "as long as we work with at most two sentence letters"?

Comment: I've edited the question and added my specific operator. Surprisingly, it's also symmetric, and has the same result for different permutations

Comment: @User: If $\#$ were complete, it could generate every Boolean function of two letters. I show that it cannot do so, so it must be incomplete. In the description of $T$, is $\oplus$ exclusive OR?

Comment: Yes, question edited

Answer (score 1):

A simplified form of your operator is:

$T = \neg X  \lor \neg Y  \lor W Z \lor \neg W \neg Z$

For $ W \ne Z $ this becomes:

$T = \neg X \lor \neg Y = \neg (X Y)$

This is a NAND with two inputs and thus a universal operator.

Comment: But I can't rely on $ W \ne Z $...

Comment: If you are not allowed to assign constants to $W$ and $Z$, the operator $T$ is not universal. $T(x,x,x,x)$ yields $true$, but there is no combination of inputs to get a constant $false$.

Answer (score 1):

Following [this relevant question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/99784/a-universal-operator-necessarily-generates-neg-x-for-input-x-x) which I asked on cs.stackexchange, a relatively general and easy way that works many times is to use the property that if an operator $T$ is universal, then necessarily $T(x,...,x)=\neg x$. In your case:
$$T(x,x,x,x)=(\neg x \vee \neg x\vee \neg x)\oplus(xxx)=\neg x\oplus x=1$$
And since this isn't $\neg x$, then $T$ necessarily isn't universal.